# How to bundle up multiple associations with the same set of options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-one, has-many-polymorphs

I have the following code in my model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :main_image, class_name: 'Image', as: :viewable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :image_one,  class_name: 'Image', as: :viewable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :image_two,  class_name: 'Image', as: :viewable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :image_three, class_name: 'Image', as: :viewable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Now, is there a way to efficiently write this code: to sum the four lines in one?

I have tried the following:

```
has_one :main_image, :image_one, :image_two, :image_three, :image_four,
          class_name: 'Image', as: :viewable, dependent: :destroy
```

Or, there may be another better way as to use `has_many` relationships, and limit the number.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is probably this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

have an image_type if that floats your records